# loop through django template context and jquery object at the same time

Tags: jquery, django

I think that the concept is right here but it doesn't seem to work and it's not showing any errors or warnings in the console.

I'm checking checkboxes based on my Django template context.  I know that the context is working.

```
    {% for neighborhood in neighborhoods %}
        $('#neighborhood_id').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val()=={{neighborhood}}){
                $(this).attr("checked","checked");
                }
            });
    {% endfor %}
```

thanks

Comment: The page is already created by the time the JavaScript runs. See the page source.

Comment: I did and the context rendered correctly, it's just not checking the boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around `{{neighborhood}}` (I am assuming that it's a string). Also, `$('#neighborhood_id').each` looks wrong (not that you aren't allowed to do it) because you are not supposed to reuse IDs, having an `each` there seems like you have more than one. Lastly, why can't you just check them in your Django template?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I posted too early.  i had duplicate #neighborhood_id in my markup that was screwing it up.